# Issues with cropping an image using java image.getSubimage

Tags: java, image, crop

I have an image that has dimensions of 16x6080. This is a stacked image that contains country flags in 16x16 sections. My goal is to pull only a specific countries flag from this image and save it as its own file. Here is my current code

```
            //Original Image
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(countryImageNamePath));

        System.out.println("Original Image Dimension: "+image.getWidth()+"x"+image.getHeight());

        //Get the cropped image
        BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(0, 1808, 16, 16);

        //Create a file to stream the out buffered image to
        File croppedFile = new File(countryImagePath + countryName + ".gif");

        //Write the cropped file
        ImageIO.write(out, "gif", croppedFile);
```

The output produced is

```
Original Image Dimension: 16x6080
Write File : C:\Applications\WorldCoinParser\images\country\US.gif
```

It doesn't matter what value I enter for the Y coordinates I always get the top part of the image starting at x=0 and y=0 with a width and height of 16.

Does anyone see where I am messing up?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your snippet of code. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), one that uses an online image available to all.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug within java 6 (and lower) trying to parse a gif file. Upgrading to Java7 fixed the issue.

Comment: Well bust my buttons and no kidding?! Thanks for getting back to us on this. Consider posting this as an answer to your question.

Comment: Since I'm a newbie here I have to wait 8 hours to post an answer. I'll update with an answer a little later today.

Answer (score 0):

As @MattPerry said, we can solve this problem just upgrading to Java 7.

Just for documentation purposes, the bug seems to be this one https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6795544 and affected Java 6.

```
The reason of problem here is that the optimized writing loop (utilized 
 direct access to image data buffer) does not take into account a data 
 band offset (which is non-trivial for sub-images, for example). It results 
 in writing image data starting from top left corner of the parent image 
 instead of expected top left corner of the sub-image.

 We  should take into account data bands offset, calculated by translated
 raster instance.
```

I could reproduce this bug using JDK5

And it works with JDK7