# java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage ignores x,y coordinates (jdk-11.0.9.11-hotspot)

Tags: java, image, crop

I'm trying to divide a jpg file into 8x8 sub images.
My output gives me 64 *identical* png files, seemingly all with coordinates (0,0).
According to an older issue [Issues with cropping an image using java image.getSubimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854069/issues-with-cropping-an-image-using-java-image-getsubimage) this was once a bug which was solved by upgrading to java 7.
I'm using jdk-11.0.9.11-hotspot.

My code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int columnCount = 8;
        int rowCount = 8;
        String fileName = args[0];//e.g. C:\picturetest\mypicture.jpg
        String fileNameNoExt = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        int heightFragment = image.getHeight() / rowCount;
        int widthFragment = image.getWidth() / columnCount;

        for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
                ImageIO.write(image
                        .getSubimage(x, y, widthFragment, heightFragment), "jpg", new File(fileNameNoExt + "-(" + x + "," + y + ").png"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure they are *identical*? You seem to forget to multiply x/y with the tile size. I don't think the bug you refer to is relevant for the version of Java you are using.

Comment: yes, I'm sure it's not a bug on my side. Following code also gives me upper left corner.  ```ImageIO.write(image
                .getSubimage(1, 1, image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2), "jpg", new File(fileNameNoExt + "-(" + 1 + "," + 1 + ").png"));```

Comment: But it’s supposed to give you the upper left corner (only 1 pixel off)..?

Answer (score 0):

They are not all starting at (0,0) - but they are starting at the positions (0,0); (0,1); (0,2) and so on until the last starts at (7,7).

You want to increase the top/left coordinates not by 1, but by `widthFragment` and `heightFragment`.

One way to do this is:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
            ImageIO.write(image
                    .getSubimage(x*widthFragment, y*heightFragment, widthFragment, heightFragment), "jpg", new File(fileNameNoExt + "-(" + x + "," + y + ").png"));
        }
    }
```

Or you change the step sizes for x and y:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x += widthFragment) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y += heightFragment) {
            ImageIO.write(image
                    .getSubimage(x, y, widthFragment, heightFragment), "jpg", new File(fileNameNoExt + "-(" + x/widthFragment + "," + y/heightFragment + ").png"));
        }
    }
```